# What is the maximum area of this structure made out of triangles?

Tags: trigonometry, area

[image]

If each of the $6$ fully drawn segments are of length $1$ m, what is the maximum area of the shape to the nearest cm$^2$?

This problem is sourced from [this contest document aimed at high school students](https://www.fsjm.ch/static/archives/19_41_CH_fr_questions.pdf).

My first thoughts were to consider the left half of the figure, divide it in $2$ right triangles and a rectangle, and let the measures of the two bottom angles of the triangles be $A$ and $B$. the area of the shape is then $\cos A \sin A +\cos B \sin B + 2 \sin A \cos B$. From now there are multiple possibilities, including using sine and cosine formulas for sums or even using the Cauchy Schwartz inequality, but I found no success. I'm looking for any solution even if they involve Calculus.

Answer for reference is

> $24 142$ cm$^2$

Comment: What's the source of this question? Knowing this can give some clue about the level of sophistication needed to solve it. ... There would seem to be three variables in play: two to control the shapes of the triangles along the bottom, and one to control the separation of those triangles. Optimizing over three variables can get pretty involved. Are there unstated assumptions here? For instance, can we assume the two triangles are identical?

Comment: I added the source, it's from a math contest and this question is for high schoolers from grade 10 to 12 (So Calculus shouldn't be required)

Also, I don't think there are $3$ variables because if you optimize the left part, the right part is by symmetry the same, so yeah we can assume logically that the left and right parts are identical although not mentionned in the question (and not necessary as you can deduce that).

Comment: Something that might help is that I think the two triangles on the sides must be isosceles and congruent.

Comment: What exactly are "grade 10 to 12"? If this is the level of 16-year-olds in contests, basic calculus and trigonometry are certain within scope as solution pathways.

Comment: do the downward segments connected to the base of negative slope have to touch the base?

Comment: @Nij Yeah from 15 to 17. Where I live, we first learn calculus at 17 so I thought there might be a non-calculus approach but even if calculus is necessary I’d like to see the solution.

Comment: @MaximusFastidiousIrreverence I’m not sure if I understand what you mean but the $4$ segments at the bottom must touch the base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer from someone else so here it is if anyone's interested (it involves no Calculus) :

First, make a reflection of the figure to the other side of the base. We have a octagon with all side lengths $1$ and it is well known that the octagon with the largest area is regular, and the area of an octogon of side length $s$ comes out as :

$A=2s^2(1+\sqrt{2})$ (can be shown with trig)

Substituting $s=1$ and dividing by $2$ yields the area in $m^2$

$A=1+\sqrt{2}$ or approximately $24142$cm$^2$